# How to integrate vue-cli with existing unrelated webpack setup in the same project?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, build, integration, vue-cli

I have a project with an existing webpack setup and it's unrelated to Vue.

Until now I have multiple entry points setups and some of these entry points are opening some iframes popups, and the plan is to build these iframes with VUE.

This means that I will also have multiple VUE entry points, this shouldn't be a problem but what I can't figure out is:

- what is the best way to add VUE-cli into this already existing setup and use the same node_modules folder
- Also to be able to add the vue-cli build commands to be run/triggered after my existing webpack build commands.

Let me know if more details are needed?

Comment: I upvoted because I'm curious if there's a way, but considering [how webpack config works](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) with vue-cli, I think it's impossible. vue-cli presumes to own the webpack config, so I don't think it can be "part of" existing webpack project. I think you would have to reconfigure everything with `vue.config.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figure it out and it turn out that you can have both in the same project.

I've used `vue create` on my existing project folder and there is a prompt with a `merge` options.

Unfortunately it deleted my dependencies but was not such a big deal. Just had to reinstall them.

Now my project's `webpack` configuration remained completely separate form `vue-cli` which is handled by the `vue.config.js` and this is exactly what I wanted.

I am using something like this to build everything at once:

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js && vue-cli-service build"
```